# How to add two class in span tag?

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

I am using `bootstrap 5` and `bootstrap-select` .

I have a PSD like this

[image: psd]

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-select.css">
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="col-md-6 mx-auto">
        <label for="color_id">Colors</label>
        <select class="form-control selectpicker" id="color_id" name="color_id[]" data-live-search="true">
            <option value="1" data-content="<span class=badge bg-danger>Red</span>">
                Red
            </option>
            <option value="2" data-content="<span class=badge bg-warning>Warning</span>">
                Warning
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I open the `inspact` I see this code

[image: inspact]

I see that these codes are missing

`bg-danger`

But I see this demo.

[[image: demo][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPhHf.png)

Both the text color is white and the background color is white. Nothing is clear.

Comment: add quotes around the class names: `class='badge bg-warning'`

Comment: @rayhatfield - Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this for multiple classes:

```html
<option value="1" data-content="<span class='badge bg-danger'>Red</span>">
                Red
</option>
```

You didn't use the quotation marks here:
`class="badge bg-danger"`

Comment: That's already within a double-quoted attribute value, so you should use single-quotes around the class names in this case, so it will not break the attribute.